# Check db_merge status whether inserted or updated

Tags: 7, database

I am using `db_merge()` in my code, and I would like to print a status message with `drupal_set_message()` that reports if the record has been added or updated.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`MergeQuery::execute()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21query.inc/function/MergeQuery%3A%3Aexecute/7) returns [`MergeQuery::STATUS_INSERT`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21query.inc/constant/MergeQuery%3A%3ASTATUS_INSERT/7) when the data was inserted in the database table, and [`MergeQuery::STATUS_UPDATE`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21query.inc/constant/MergeQuery%3A%3ASTATUS_UPDATE/7) when a row was updated.

`MergeQuery` is the class of the object returned from [`db_merge()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_merge/7).

```
public function execute() {
  if (!count($this->condition)) {
    throw new InvalidMergeQueryException(t('Invalid merge query: no conditions'));
  }
  $select = $this->connection->select($this->conditionTable)
    ->condition($this->condition);
  $select->addExpression('1');
  if (!$select->execute()->fetchField()) {
    try {
      $insert = $this->connection->insert($this->table)->fields($this->insertFields);
      if ($this->defaultFields) {
        $insert->useDefaults($this->defaultFields);
      }
      $insert->execute();
      return self::STATUS_INSERT;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
      // The insert query failed, maybe it's because a racing insert query
      // beat us in inserting the same row. Retry the select query, if it
      // returns a row, ignore the error and continue with the update
      // query below.
      if (!$select->execute()->fetchField()) {
        throw $e;
      }
    }
  }
  if ($this->needsUpdate) {
    $update = $this->connection->update($this->table)
      ->fields($this->updateFields)
      ->condition($this->condition);
    if ($this->expressionFields) {
      foreach ($this->expressionFields as $field => $data) {
        $update->expression($field, $data['expression'], $data['arguments']);
      }
    }
    $update->execute();
    return self::STATUS_UPDATE;
  }
}
```